# Single line of code to retrieve a value from an Array in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

So I'm working in Java and I have a HashMap that stores a String key with an Integer Array. This is what the declaration looks like:

```
public HashMap<String, int[]> playerPoints = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
```

My question is is it possible to retrieve the first integer of the array for a certain key in a simple line of code. I understand that I can do it this way:

```
tempArray = playerPoints.get(String);
int firstValue = tempArray[0];
```

But is there a way to do it in one line of code?

Comment: `playerPoints.get(String)[0]`, assuming the key is present in the Map, and the corresponding array value is not empty.

Comment: @Eran You can also use getOrDefault() and have a default/special value for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Integer[] myArr = {2, 3, 5};

    HashMap<String, Integer[]> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("el", myArr);
    System.out.println(hashMap.get("el")[0].toString());
```

The output will be `2`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in one line, for example with default 0

```
int firstValue = playerPoints.isEmpty() ? 0 : playerPoints.get("String").length == 0 ? 0 : playerPoints.get("String")[0];
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a try.

Comment: `length <= 0`? Really? When could `length` ever be negative?